# Как сохранить консинстентность между двумя кусками кода в приложении которые дублируют бизнес логику?

Tags: java, проектирование

Есть проблема, в проекте на java с некоторым MVC фреймворком, есть два места с дублированием логики сохранения пользователя.

Специфика приложения такова, что

1. Ведется аудит изменений состояния(полей) юзера при сохранении. При чем у него много дочерних объектов.
2. И из этого аудита восстанавливается состояние юзера.
3. При воcстановлении нужно учесть порядок вызова методов, выполнения некоторых дополнительных действий вроде отправки сообщения на email о создании.

Основная проблема в поддержки данной функциональности то что юзер сохраняется в двух местах

1. В контроллере из бина с данных полученых с клиента.
2. С аудита в аудит менеджере.

И при дальнейшем изменении в контроллере либо порядка сохранения либо добавление новых/удаление полей юзера нужно как то сохранить консистентность в контроллере и в аудит менеджере.

Comment: А в чем проблема устранить дублирование и вынести логику сохранения пользователя в отдельный класс(ы)?

Comment: Если кратко, то слишком много рефакторить, плюс создание промежуточной абстракции. Однако уже нашел кажется подходящие для моей ситуации решение. Это **всегда** сохранять изменения из аудита.